# can't make juju charm-store server?

Tags: server, bash, juju

I am trying to run juju charm-server in my local machine.I followed these steps.(https://github.com/juju/charmstore) but it gives this error.When i enter make command it gives this one.

`Makefile:49: *** Cannot build; /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/charm-store-server/charmstore is not on GOPATH.  Stop`

in my bash file i have added

```
GOROOT=/home/sajith/install/go/go
GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup/charm-store-server/charmstore
```

and then export GOROOT and GOPATH

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$GOROOT/bin
export GOROOT
export GOPATH
```

I want to know how to setup these GO variable for run juju charm-store server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have charmstore at
`GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup/charm-store-server/charmstore`
as you have written, however, then you need to change GOPATH for any other project.

I would recommend setting the GOPATH to:

1. mkdir /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/go
2. export GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup/go
3. mkdir $GOPATH/src

Do the

```
go get -u -v -t github.com/juju/charmstore/...
```

The charmstore code is located in:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/juju/charmstore
```

Then execute:

1. `make deps`
2. `make sysdeps`
3. `make install`

Edit your question with new data to see if this helps.

Comment: Hi i have done what you said.But when i run make deps it gives this error.godeps -u dependencies.tsv
make: godeps: Command not found
make: *** [deps] Error 127

Comment: Try adding this: go get launchpad.net/godeps/...   When the command finished, check if godeps is in $PATH and rerun make deps.

Comment: Hi now charmstore server is running on 8080.But i can't retrieve any commands like /charm-info or /charm-event it always gives empty bracket."{}" so i can see charms in mongodb